# How to recursively clone a repository for the GitHub app

Tags: git, github, github-app

I'm developing a Github app that needs to be able to clone GitHub repositories whenever a push event occurs.

I've successfully set everything up including the server and can [clone repositories using using access tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#http-based-git-access-by-an-installation). However, I'm having some trouble with repositories that have [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

I find that using `git clone --recurse-submodules https://x-access-token:<token>@github.com/owner/repo.git` doesn't work if `repo.git` has submodules configured with SSH. Is there an easy way to perform recursive submodule fetching with access tokens?

I tried another approach which involved using the private key `.pem` file for my github app as an SSH identity. This involved running `ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /path/to/private-key.pem; git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:owner/repo.git'`, but that ended up with a `Permission denied (publickey)` error which makes sense since the `.pem` file isn't meant to have access to repositories, just to authenticate the GitHub app.

What is the right way to perform recursive submodule cloning/fetching when writing a GitHub app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think using HTTPS will be easier for submodules, you can add to your configuration:

```
 git -c url."https://x-access-token:<token>@github.com/".insteadOf='git@github.com/' clone ...
```

For any submodule with a GitHub SSH URL, that would use an HTTPS URL instead (with your access token).

Comment: Incredible idea! It worked flawlessly (except I think the  `'` that precedes `url` is extraneous. Thank you!

Comment: @PaymahnMoghadasian Great! I have edited the answer and removed the extraneous `'`